# Trying to add class to dynamic selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a page I am working on, each of the list-items's have an attribute data-number with the value of the number that the `<li>` is in the list.

The list-item's correspond to slides and I am trying to apply the class `.current` to the list-items that corresponds to the slide that is currently being viewed.

The slide that is currently being viewed can be get by the function `.getIndex()` and then I have to style the li with that data-attribute of that number with the class current.

I tried to do that with the following, but it is not working:

```
$('li[data-number="'+k.getIndex();+'"]').addClass('current');
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how I can achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML so that we can see your `<li>`'s and how the fit in the overall page?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because of your semicolon after `getIndex` function. Try to remove it and see how:

```
$('li[data-number="'+k.getIndex();+'"]').addClass('current');
---------------------------------^here-----------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the selector is working. Run it in either firebug or chrome developer tools to make sure you're selecting the correct element.

edit:
for that matter, make sure k is pointing to the right element and it's defined. Check your console for errors.

edit 2:
and you don't need the ";"

Comment: `$('li[data-number="1"]').addClass('current');` works fine or with any other number in place of 1.